# Пагинация и Отзывы

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Ребят нужна пагинация, постраничная навигация с этим кодом, максимальное кол-во отзывов 5, после превышения уже переходит на 2 нумерацию, выручайте братцы программисты нудна ваша помощь, Спасибо заранее братцы буду признателен)

```
    index.php.   


    <?php


     require "shout.php";


    ?>
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        </head>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="add_comment.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
        <input  type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" style="margin-left:15px; width:50%"  placeholder="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea style="width:50%; margin-left:15px;" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="7" name="content"></textarea>   
      </div>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-left:15px; ">Send</button>
    </form>

          <?php     
        $comments = getAllComments(); 
        if($comments!=null){ 
        foreach($comments as $n){ 
        ?> 
        <div class="card mt-3" style="width: 100%; background-color:#FF5349";> 
        <div class="card-body"> 
        <h5 class="card-title"> 
        <?php echo $n['name']; ?> at <?php echo $n['post_date']; ?> 
        </h5> 
        <p class="card-text" style=""> 

        </p> 
        </div>  
        </div> 

         <?php 
        echo htmlspecialchars($n['content']); 
        }
        }
        ?> 

        </body>

    </html>

/////////////////////////////////////////////

shout.php

 <?php

  $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Ors','root','');




        function addComents( $name, $content){
           global  $connection;
        $query = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO comments (id, name, content, post_date)
            VALUES (NULL, :name, :content, NOW())
        ");

        $query->execute(
            array( 
                "name"=>$name,
                "content"=>$content 
            )
        );
        }





function getAllComments(){

    global $connection;

       $query = $connection->prepare("
                    SELECT * FROM comments 
                "); 

                $query->execute();

                $result = $query->fetchAll();


    return $result;

    }

?>

////////////////////////////////////////////

add_comment.php

     <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

require "shout.php";

    if(isset($_POST['content'])&&isset($_POST['name'])){

        addComents( $_POST['name'], $_POST['content']);

    }
}

header("Location:index.php")

?>
```

Comment: Почему никто не может ответить???

Comment: Наверное потому, что человек, котороый мог бы ответить ещё не видел вашего вопроса. Также ваш вопрос предполагает очень много кода и объяснений в ответе - за пару минут ответ не написать. По сути вопроса - вам надо примерно так действовать: 1. Запрашивать с БД не все комменты, а порциями, используя offset&limit в запросе (в разных БД синтаксис может быть разный). 2. Постраничный вывод можно очень по разному сделать. Например нарисовав в HTML (КОЛ_ВО_КОММЕНТОВ/КОЛ_ВО_КОММЕНТОВ_НА СТРАНИЦЕ) кнопок и открывать другую страницу, передавая туда её номер, который будет аргументом запроса в БД.

Comment: Прошу прощения, просто заказчик попросил так сделать, а я никогда этого не делал и не знаю как  и поэтому тороплюсь чутка, еще раз извиняюсь,  а отказываться не вариант я уже все сделал осталось только проблему с нумерацией решить эту)

Comment: Статей в интернете про пагинацию более чем дохрена. Но читать их не наш путь. Если вы в php понимаете менее чем полностью, то на фрилансе можете заказать сделать всё за вас

Comment: Не я лучше сам,  там многом инфы насчет пагинаций, но не с моим же кодом,  а мне нужна пагинация с моим кодом)

Comment: @РустамАбдурасулов не уверен, что вам нужно заниматься тем, чем вы занимаетесь на данный момент. Пагинация - одна из базовых основ, которую нужно понять и уметь писать с закрытыми глазами. Относительно того, что в интернете много примеров и уже готовых решений, но не под ваш код, могу с уверенностью сказать, ваш код чем-то особенным не является, можете глянуть любую пагинацию для блога или форума, вам подойдет. Код из вашего `add_comment.php`, в разрезе пагинации вообще не нужен...

Comment: Благодарю за совет, но я в нем не нуждался, а нуждался я в коде или помощи, так как я никогда не занимался пагинацией.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так получите строчки 6 по 15:

```
SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date LIMIT 5,10;
```

Передавайте параметрами, предварительно задав нужные значения.