# Отзывы и База данных

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

Ребят проблема такая, все работает, но я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы если скопилось много отзывов перекидывало на другую страницу, точнее оставалось на той же странице, но уже например на 2 нумерации и тд, например 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 и тд, когда будет достигнут лимит отзывов должно следующий отзыв перекидывать на 2 страницу и тд, как это осуществить с этим кодом, нужен алгоритм на php или что, НАДЕЮСЬ НА ВАШУ ПОМОЩЬ БРАТЦЫ!)) Заранее спасибо.

```
index.php.   


    <?php


     require "shout.php";


    ?>
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        </head>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="add_comment.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
        <input  type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" style="margin-left:15px; width:50%"  placeholder="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea style="width:50%; margin-left:15px;" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="7" name="content"></textarea>   
      </div>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-left:15px; ">Send</button>
    </form>

          <?php     
        $comments = getAllComments(); 
        if($comments!=null){ 
        foreach($comments as $n){ 
        ?> 
        <div class="card mt-3" style="width: 100%; background-color:#FF5349";> 
        <div class="card-body"> 
        <h5 class="card-title"> 
        <?php echo $n['name']; ?> at <?php echo $n['post_date']; ?> 
        </h5> 
        <p class="card-text" style=""> 

        </p> 
        </div>  
        </div> 

         <?php 
        echo htmlspecialchars($n['content']); 
        }
        }
        ?> 

        </body>

    </html>

/////////////////////////////////////////////

shout.php

 <?php

  $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Ors','root','');




        function addComents( $name, $content){
           global  $connection;
        $query = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO comments (id, name, content, post_date)
            VALUES (NULL, :name, :content, NOW())
        ");

        $query->execute(
            array( 
                "name"=>$name,
                "content"=>$content 
            )
        );
        }





function getAllComments(){

    global $connection;

       $query = $connection->prepare("
                    SELECT * FROM comments 
                "); 

                $query->execute();

                $result = $query->fetchAll();


    return $result;

    }

?>

////////////////////////////////////////////

add_comment.php

     <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

require "shout.php";

    if(isset($_POST['content'])&&isset($_POST['name'])){

        addComents( $_POST['name'], $_POST['content']);

    }
}

header("Location:index.php")

?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отзывы Базза данных и перелистывание страниц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086748/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86)